# Display of spam vs normal flags on flag summary inconsistent

Tags: bug, flag-history

As I was going through my flag summary on Stack Overflow, I noticed that we display different information depending on what kind of flag it is.

[image]

These are the differences that I noticed:

1. "flagged as" prepended to the spam flag
2. My username is included in the normal flag
3. The time that I flagged with the normal flag is included in the display